# Python script not executing under lighttpd

Tags: python, lighttpd

I'm under Debian,
Installed python and lighttpd using "apt-get install"

Here is my lighttpd conf file:

```
server.modules = (
        "mod_access",
        "mod_alias",
        "mod_compress",
        "mod_redirect",
        "mod_rewrite",
        "mod_cgi"
)

server.document-root        = "/var/www/html"
server.upload-dirs          = ( "/var/cache/lighttpd/uploads" )
server.errorlog             = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
server.pid-file             = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"
server.username             = "www-data"
server.groupname            = "www-data"
server.port                 = 80


index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html", "index.lighttpd.html" )
url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc" )
static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )

compress.cache-dir          = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/"
compress.filetype           = ( "application/javascript", "text/css", "text/html", "text/$

# default listening port for IPv6 falls back to the IPv4 port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/use-ipv6.pl " + server.port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl"
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/include-conf-enabled.pl"

# configuration cgi-python
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^cgi-bin/" {
         cgi.assign = ( ".py" => "/usr/bin/python" )
}
```

I have this file under /var/www/html/cgi-bin/

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data  245 mai   19 12:09 hello.py
```

hello.py:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
#
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n"
print '<html><head><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />'
print '<title>Rapsberry Pi</title><p>'
for count in range(1,100):
   print 'Hello&nbsp;World...'
print "</p></body></html>"
```

My problem is that the browser does not execute my file and display my .py code.
No errors in the  /var/log/lighttpd/error.log 
Anyone has an idea about what is going wrong ?

Comment: I wish web servers had better documentation for such common tasks. A lot of devs use Python as backend yet there is little official documentation :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs here:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/lighttpd#CGI

it appears you need also need to set `cgi.assign`, e.g.:

```
cgi.assign                 = ( ".pl"  => "/usr/bin/perl",
                               ".cgi" => "/usr/bin/perl",
                               ".rb"  => "/usr/bin/ruby",
                               ".erb" => "/usr/bin/eruby",
                               ".py"  => "/usr/bin/python",
                               ".php" => "/usr/bin/php-cgi" )
```

Comment: Great ! I removed my cgi conf in the lighttpd.conf and enable 10-cgi.conf